# Extract string part in c#

Tags: c#, parsing

I need to parse string records in a column to break it up into 2 parts. 2 examples of the records that I need to break up are:

1. Row.3.1.1
2. Qa.2.1

For each record, I require everything before the last '.' and everything after the last '.' e.g. for #1 above, I would need:

Code = Row.3.1
RValue = 1

I am a novice to c# and have tried the following but not getting the desired result:

```
string ID = "Row.3.1.1;

int CodeIndex = ID.LastIndexOf(".");
string Code = ID.Substring(CodeIndex);

int ValueIndex = ID.IndexOf(".");
Rstring RValue = ID.Substring(ValueIndex);
```

Comment: That code example won't compile -- is this issue related to compilation or the actual results? Please post the incorrect results, error message, or everything that was giving you grief during your trials. It's hard to know exactly what the issue is at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var firstTest = "Row.3.1.1";
            var secondTest = "Qa.2.1";

            Console.WriteLine(BuildFromString(firstTest));
            Console.WriteLine(BuildFromString(secondTest));

            Console.Read();
        }

        public static Extract BuildFromString(string input)
        {
            return new Extract
            {
                Code = input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf('.')),
                RValue = input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf('.'))
            };
        }

        public class Extract
        {
            public string Code { get; set; }
            public string RValue { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"Code: {Code} RValue:{RValue}";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Good effort but your indices are slightly off.

```
string ID = "Row.3.1.1";

int CodeIndex = ID.LastIndexOf(".");

//get the first half which is from index 0 (the start) to where the last `.` was found
string Code = ID.Substring(0, CodeIndex);

//start from where the last '.' and move up one because we 
//don't want to include the `.` in RValue
string RValue = ID.Substring(CodeIndex + 1);
```

You may want to include error handling and such (e.g. what happens if there is no `.`. in the string). But assuming you have the perfect string, the code above should work.

Answer (score -1):

I think this the code you are looking for:

```
string ID = "Row.3.1.1";
int CodeIndex = ID.LastIndexOf(".");
string Code = ID.Substring(0, CodeIndex);
string RValue = ID.Substring(CodeIndex + 1);
```

See .Net [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qFNhbu) code

Also, you might want to read up on [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) function on MSDN.

Answer (score -1):

you dont need two index operations. (If I am reading the requirements correctly)

```
   string ID = "Row.3.1.1";
   int codeIndex = ID.LastIndexOf(".");
   string code = ID.Substring(0, codeIndex);
   string rValue = ID.Substring(codeIndex + 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are close:

```
string ID = "Row.3.1.1;

int CodeIndex = ID.LastIndexOf(".");
string Code = ID.Substring(CodeIndex);

// int ValueIndex = ID.IndexOf(".");
Rstring RValue = ID.Substring(0, CodeIndex); //Here, (0, CodeIndex)
```

Comment: Code and RValue are the opposite

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility without substring and lastindexof:

```
var IDParts = ID.Split('.');
var RValue = IDParts[IDParts.Length-1];
var Code = ID.TrimEnd("." + RValue);
```

For all solutions in any answer, be aware, that they throw exceptions or in my case produce false results, if there is no '.' in your ID. So you should add a check for that.

Comment: There is a chance that RValue can be more than a char. But only OP knows...

Answer (score -1):

Regular expressions make this easy.  No indexes or offsets required.

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^(.*)\.([^\.]*)$");

string testString= "Row.3.1.1";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.GroupCollection groups = regex.Match(testString).Groups;
System.Console.WriteLine("Code = " + groups[1]);
System.Console.WriteLine("RValue = " + groups[2]);
```